# Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context

Tags: validation

this is my first post 
just the site i needed cause im kinda new to all this

im trying to validate my page and there is 1 error that i dont know what to do with
 Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

if i remove the div part
my page is not looking the same as it does with it and it works on all browsers right now with the errors

this is the piece of code that is making the error

```
                         <div class="picture_content margin-left">
            <ul class="image_box_story2">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="images/slider1.jpg"  alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/slider2.jpg" alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/slider3.jpg" alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

any help on how to fix this would be apreciated alot
thanks for taking the time

btw i downloaded a bootstrap temp and the Original file has the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is

```
            <ul class="image_box_story2">
```

a ul is a list and can only have li children, not div, that list doesn't have any li children at all.

Perhaps you can change it to `<div class="image_box_story2">` (and change (`</ul>` to `</div>`) that would make it valid, but whether it displays Ok depends on the css you have not shown.

Comment: thank you so much that fixed it and it seems that everything is still in place